# Regular expression for language with even number of 0's and 1's

Tags: regular-expressions

Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$. What is the regular expression for the language of all strings with an even number of $0$'s and an even number of $1$'s?

If we only require an even number of $0$'s, the language $(1^*)\mid(1^*01^*01^*)^*$ works. But once there is a requirement on both $0$'s and $1$'s, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: This feels like a duplicate. Anyone?

Comment: [Need Regular Expression for Finite Automata: Even number of `1`s and Even number of `0`s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17434694/1673391)

Comment: additionally I believe just even number of `0`s can be written as simply written as `(1 + 01*0)*`  your regex is complete

Comment: some leads given in http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/41874/157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructing regular expressions is usually more complicated than programming finite state automata. The standard way would be to construct a FSA and translate that one into a regular expression using standard techniques.

But if you prefer, it can be done directly, in two steps. Start by making two regular expressions $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

- First $\alpha$ specifies strings with *even* number of $1$'s, and exactly two
  $0$'s, one of which is the last symbol of the string.
- Similarly $\beta$ specifies strings with *odd* number of $1$'s, and exactly two $0$'s,
  one of which is the last symbol of the string.

Then build an expression for strings that have an even number of $0$ ánd an even number of $1$'s based on  $\alpha$ and $\beta$.