# Design the regular expression and DFA that accepts a language in which "110" is no less than "011"

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

The question is to design a DFA that accepts a language in which the count of  substring "$110$" is no less than the count of substring "$011$". For example, $110$, "0101", "0111101110" is good but "011011" is bad.

The restriction of the language equivalently means whenever a "011" is encountered, only this pattern "$0111^*0$" is allowed, so that a "$011$" is matched with a "$110$". There is no other restriction.

I tried to give a regular expression as $(1^*0111^*0)^* + 1^*0^*$, but I tried very hard but failed to convert this to a DFA. Is there a systematic way to convert such a regular expression to a DFA?

Comment: @HendrikJan this is a duplicate of different questions. RE -> DFA (at the end is the question about systematic conversion). So it goes for the reference one.

Comment: For example [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40819/how-to-create-dfa-from-regular-expression-without-using-nfa).