# FSA for $(ab)^*(cb^n)^*$

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, context-sensitive

> How can I prove that this language is regular, possibly by making a finite automata for this: $(ab)^*(cb^n)^*$, where $n\ge1$?

An automaton can easily be drawn for the part $(ab)^*$, but the part $(cb^n)^*$ doesn't seem to be regular because if the Kleene closure is taken $\ge2$ times, then it will be of the form $(cb^n)(cb^n)$, which reduces to string matching and is context-sensitive.

This was actually a question, solution to which said that the above language has the following regular expression: $(ab)^*(cbb^*)^*$.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in $(cb^n)^*$. Does it mean words like $cb^ncb^n\cdots cb^n$ or $cb^{n_1}cb^{n_2}\cdots cb^{n_k}$, where $n_i\ge1$? If it is the former, then the language is not regular and cannot be accepted by a finite automaton! However, if we consider $C$ is the languages of words of the form $cb^n$ where $n\ge1$, then $C^*$ should be interpreted as the the latter, by the definition of Kleene closure.  Can you provide a url or reference to the original problem?

Comment: With a moment of reflection, it seems the only interpretation that can make sense is the latter. The former is not compatible with the usage of parenthesis (meaning, highest priority) and the definition of Kleene star.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I can't give url as it was a question from an online practice test. But the explanation given in the solution said that it's regular since it can be written like $(ab)^*(cbb^*)^*$, which is basically the latter interpretation.

Comment: Do you still want an answer given $(ab)^*(cbb^*)^*$? By the way, can you update your question to add that regular expression?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes I still want answer, so as to be able to decide unambiguously between the two interpretations pointed by you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions)

Comment: @virmis_007 If you want to know how to interpret the question, you should ask the person who set it to you, not us, and point out that their notation is ambiguous.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I believe you meant [How to create DFA from regular expression without using NFA?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40819) or [Convert regular expression to DFA](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13599).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Actually I wanted to ask whether the language is regular, and how is it so. I should've framed the question more appropriately. I questioned the possibility of existence of automata  just because it is a way to prove that language is regular.

Comment: @virmis_007 You've given us a regular expresion, so the language is regular. I'm not sure what else you're looking for. (And our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/9550) already explains how to show that langauges are regular.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the correct/sensible interpretation, $(ab)^*(cbb^*)^*$, I will list the states and its corresponding regular expressions below; you can figure out the transitions between the states.

$q_{0}$: $(ab)^*$, start state
$q_{1}$: $(ab)^*a$
$q_{2}$: $(ab)^*(cbb^*)^*c$
$q_{3}$: $(ab)^*(cbb^*)^*$, accepting state
$q_{4}$: for all other strings, rejecting state/dead-end state

For the incorrect/unlikely interpretation, where $(cb^n)^*$ means all words like the empty word, $cb^n$, $cb^ncb^n$ and $cb^ncb^n\cdots cb^n$ for some $n\ge1$, the corresponding language is not regular since its intersection with the language with regular expression $cb^*cb^*$, $\{cb^ncb^n\mid n\ge1\}$ is not a regular language. So there is no FSA for that language.