# How to convert a null state transition in nfa to dfa

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

i am looking to convert regular expression 0* 1* to deterministic finite automaton (DFA)

[image]

I have tried creating the NFA for the regular expression as given in the above image,

From the regular expression, the strings that can be created are
{€, 0, 1, 001, 011, 0011, ………}

My doubt is how do you even create DFA That can have only single 0’s or single 1’s , meaning that the number of 0’s is one when number of 1’s is zero

You have to accept a single input symbol to go the next state

When I placed the regular expression in an DFA online generator I got the below automaton

[image: enter image description to]

I ask this because the main question to solve is this image, from an exam

[image]

From the above question in the image I got the regular expression

0* 1* 2*

Which was the same as the above example, thus the reason I ask the above one first

Thank you for the online free community effort you put into

Btw the site to generate automaton or final state machine is this

[final state machine generator website link](https://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/)

Comment: The DFA produced by your online generator is certainly correct. It accepts the empty string because the start state is accepting. What is it which confusesyou?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Methods to convert from regexp to DFA are described in https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/40819/755.